# Xamarin Forms: How to add controls on MasterDetail Tool Bar

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

I am creating a master detail page in Xamarin Forms. I want to have Menu icon on top left, searcher on the right and another label on the menu bar.

Can some help help me with how I can be done? I added the menu icon. I want help with adding other controls on the toolbar/Menubar/Navigation bar what ever it is called. Its the bar on top of the master detail page.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PCL.Core.Views;assembly=PCL.Core"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
        x:Class="PCL.Core.Views.RootPage" MasterBehavior="Popover" >
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="Maroon" >
            <x:Arguments >
                <local:DetailPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you talking about this kind of controls as on image than:

"Hamburger menu" image you set in MasterDetail page;
Icons (GPS and DATA on image) - are ToolbarItem's that you need to add to Detail Page

There is plenty of examples available:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17339/navigationpage-and-toolbaritems

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17351/making-a-toolbar

[image]

Comment: Yes this works great, however, please add the code to your answer and use the links for references, I'll then up-vote you.