# Xamarin forms NavigationPage.TitleView need to be on all pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a NavigationPage.TitleView that includes label with an image if I want it on all my pages do I add it to the MasterDetailPage ? NavigationPage is not available on a MasterDetailPage and if I add it to my menu page it will not display. The only page it will display from the default home page?

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MenuPage x:Name="menuPage"/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>


<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#22335c" >
        <Label Text="App Name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#22335c" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
        <Image Source="icon.jpg"  Aspect="AspectFit"  BackgroundColor="#22335c" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Comment: If you use NavigationPage properly using it at one page will affect all of them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615109/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-controls-on-masterdetail-tool-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating  a custom renderer and set it as the base class for all pages in the app. Within this custom renderer you can try to add the Label and image source to the Navigation bar.

```
public class NavigationRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private CustomTitleView _titleView;
    public NavigationSearchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var navPage = Element as NavigationSearchPage;
        if (navPage == null)
            return;

        var activity = this.Context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        _titleView= new TitleView(Context);
        toolbar.AddView(_titleView);
    }

}
```